# Big O Notation with Absolute Value?

Tags: graph, big-o, notation

I'm going through some programming interview question books, and I've seen reference to `"O(|A|)"` time complexity.  I've never seen this notation with the absolute value given.

Some research led me to [Big O Cheatsheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) that references this notation under the graphs section.  The problem I'm researching is about partitioning an array, which isn't really a graph question (though I risk perhaps showing my ignorance with that statement).

Does `|A|` refer to the magnitude of the array, or otherwise number of elements, i.e. `O(N)`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure e.g. `V` refers to the set of vertices, and `|V|` refers to its [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) (= the number of vertices).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In set theory notation `|A|` is the cardinality of set `A`, in other words the number of elements contained in set `A`.

For Reference: http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/symbols.html

Answer (score 2):

You will see this notation always when `A` is not a number.

`A` could be many things, so `|A|` depends on the context. E.g.

- `A` is a vector of a lattice, so `|A|` is the length of the vector.
- `A` is an (maybe unknown) algorithm (e.g. an attacker to an encryption), then `|A|` could be the complexity of this algorithm or the length of the random bit vector this algorithm uses.
- `A` is a set, then is `|A|` the number of elements in the set, as Kostub Deshmukh mentioned.

There can be many more cases.